# vs code mysql issue

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Has anyone run into this issue on vscode mysql?

I've searched everywhere and cannot find a solution. If anyone has any idea or has come across this, the help would be greatly appreciated.

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:33060
```

The issue is coming from the sqltools extension connection on vscode.

i hope you solve this problem

Comment: You are sure your mysql port is `33060` not `3306`

Comment: yes i am really sure

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means there is no service listening on that specific port. So either 1) you got the wrong port or 2) your mysql server is not running or 3) it is [not bound](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address) to listen to localhost